# How does websites store persistent/temporary states w/o cookies or local storage or database storage?

Tags: javascript, cookies, storage

I'm not sure how a certain website is storing its state. I have disabled setting cookies from that website( running in Chrome ). I have deleted all local and database storage from that site, but for some reason, that site can still detect somehow that its the same computer as before. How does it do that?

Comment: Client IP address tracking, Fat URL's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) for a few possibilities.

Comment: Who writes stuff like this?  If you're smart enough to implement it, aren't you smart enough to realize why you shouldn't?  Although, I have to say, I love the ETags hack.